# Multiple criteria match Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, transpose, textjoin

I have 2 tabs in google sheets that are

```
Col1  Col2
1       A
1       B
1       C
1       D
2       X
2       Y
2       Z

Col3  Col4
1      ABCD
2      XYZ
```

I want to fill Col4 with all matching values by joining Col3 and Col1, I have tried

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Vlookup(Col3,Col1,1,0))
```

but getting "Result was not automatically expanded" error

Answer (score 1):

try dragging:

```
=JOIN(, FILTER(B:B, A:A=C1))
```

[image]

---

or use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({A:A&"♦", B:B}, 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1")
 ,,999^99)), "♦"), " ", ))
```

[image: 0]